# What are the differences between the normal and the hard mode?

Tags: candy-box

I discovered that [Candy box! has a hard mode](http://aniwey.net/candies-hardmode/) while searching for Candy box! related stuff:
**http://aniwey.net/candies-hardmode/**

**What are the differences between the regular mode and the hard mode?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the two differences are
- Eating Candies does not increase your hp (your hp will be 100 all game)
- The sorceress cannot improve your sword level beyond 5 ("A mysterious force has prevented me from upgrading your sword", or some such message).

(A third difference may be an increased sense of satisfaction when you beat the game :). Enjoy! )